# MySQL query or $_SESSION variable or Cookies for non-sensitive data?

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies, optimization

My site's menu tree is three layers deep, relatively static, and completely database driven.

I made the presumption that querying the mysql database for the complete menu tree with every page load would be more resource intensive than querying it once and storing it in a $_SESSION variable. My menus take up 77,835 bytes - using `strlen(serialize($menuarray))`.

It finally occurred to me that I have no data to back up this presumption and I can't find this answer anywhere. I presume storing in a $_SESSION var eats memory whereas a mysql query essentially uses the same amount of memory (although I can unset the var after the menu is generated) but also taxes the cpu. Both of course will access the disk.

Cookies are a third option and am willing to hear arguments in their favor as well, although I hold a bias against them.

So, for non-sensitive data, would you go Query, $_SESSION, or Cookies and why?

**UPDATE**
I realized that another options would be to cache the serialized menu query output either to the database or the disk.

Or, even cache the HTML output to a file and `include` the menus when needed.

**UPDATE 2**
Just the fact that this question was put on hold hints at something - perhaps that the use of server resources is a fuzzy area. It's strange trying to optimize without a clearer sense of the impacts of memory, cpu cycles, disk access, db connections, etc.

In the end, caching makes sense and I will go with the accepted answer.

Comment: In case you can not cache static HTML output – for example because you still want the menu to be “dynamic”, in that you can f.e. add a class to the current menu item on every page, I’d suggest to simply store the data in the PHP data structure that you need for that (such as an array or an object) – that one you can easily write to a file using `var_export`, so that you get a PHP file that you can include, and have your data ready to work with.

Comment: @CBroe - I was not aware of `var_export`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you get from the database and cache the result. You'll just store the result one time, so it will not consume much memory, and you won't make a db query every time you load the page.

You can do it by simply using OPCache, Memcached, Redis, etc. Or, in another way, simply get the value from db, create a file, save the content, and get the value from the file, removing and adding again in certain time intervals.

Comment: Funny, after I wrote the question, this occurred to me and I was just updating my question with caching as another option.

Comment: Hahaha. :D Session variables will be set for each user, so it will consume much memory compared to cache. Cookies are a great option, but i do not think it is good to manage, if you change the menu, using cache, you just need to delete the file ou the cache key, and ready. If you are using cookies, you need to wait the cookie expire.

Comment: _“Cookies are a great option”_ – no, they are rather not, not for this – because they would be send back and forth between the client and the server on every request, and for a larger data structure such as a menu, that doesn’t even change between requests, that makes very little sense. Plus, users that reject cookies, or search engines, would then get no menu at all – big drawback.

Comment: Yep, agree with you. When i wrote, i was thinking "cookies are a great option for non-sensitive data", not for html data.  And about search engines, you can simply get the cookie from the back-end. But doesn't make sense to use cookies if you can use cache, in my opinion.

Comment: ... And that menu could not be stored in a cookie, the limit is 4kb.